# Call a Method when the User clicks in Dropdown in p:autocomplete

Tags: primefaces, autocomplete

I'm working with Primefaces 5.1 and would like a help in component

How I can update the FacesMessages in my page when the user performed one click in the icon from the dropdown in  autocomplete( this when the autocomplete is empty)

I've tried many ways but I can not do FacesMessage be updated, that event or how I should conduct is action?

```
<p:autoComplete id="stepDescriptionDropDownId" 
                    dropdown="true"
                    value="#{Step.stepSearch.selectedStep}"
                    converter="basedEntityConverter"
                    var="stepSearch"
                    itemValue="#{stepSearch}"
                    itemLabel="#{stepSearch.description}"
                    completeMethod="#{Step.doCompleteStepSearchDescription}"
                    panelStyleClass="autoCompletePanelBorderNone"
                    immediate="true"
                    size="30">
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{stepSearch.id.stepCode}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{stepSearch.description}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" process="@form" update="inputTextStepCodeId, :facesMessagesId" listener="#{Step.doValidateSteps}" />
</p:autoComplete>
```

In short, how can I call a method when the User clicks on the icon?

Comment: In short - `p:remoteCommand`. You have to give your icon onclick function, in this function invoke `p:remoteCommand` and then can call backing bean/update whatever you want to.

Comment: The onclick call back is for the input Text in dropdown not for the button